# Error for ERC20 transfer The constructor should be payable if you send value

Tags: contract-design, erc-20

I have two contract

1) ERC20 contract

2) ERC20 token registry contract which is invoking my token contract and making a transfer function call to the token

But function call is ending up with an error stating that the transaction to ERC20Registry.deployERC20 failed:

> VM error: revert.
>   revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
>   Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information.

Source

Token Registry Contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.24;

import './TERC20.sol';

contract ERC20Registry {
  function deployERC20(
    string _Name,
    string _Symbol,
    uint256 _initialSupply
    )
    public
    returns (address)
    {
      TERC20 token = new TERC20(_Name, _Symbol, 18, _initialSupply);
     token.transfer(tx.origin, token.totalSupply());
     return address(token);
    }
}
```

Token Contract

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.24;

import "./ERC20.sol";
import "./ERC20Detailed.sol";
import "./Ownable.sol";

contract TERC20 is ERC20, ERC20Detailed, Ownable {
  constructor (
    string memory name,
    string memory symbol,
    uint8 decimals,
    uint256 initialSupply
  ) 
  ERC20(initialSupply)
  ERC20Detailed(name, symbol, decimals) 
  public
  {
    emit Transfer(0x0, tx.origin, initialSupply);
  }
}
```

Comment: Difficult to say. I suggest you simply comment out some `require` statements from the token contract until you find out which causes it. Most likely it's some check in the `transfer` function.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit Rob, Let me check further on what you have suggested @Lauri..
But as i said transfer of ERC20 should not require function to make payable

Comment: The part about payable is just a guess from the compiler and typically it's incorrect, so you can just ignore that.

Comment: @DevrajSinghRawat What does ERC20 and ERC20Detailed look like? How do you call deployERC20? Also the Transfer event seem incorrect in TERC20.